# Angular GitHub pages app at root hides project pages app

Tags: angular, github-pages

I have an Angular app deployed to GitHub pages at `<user>.github.io` (with matching repo name) to serve as my portfolio site. I have another Angular app deployed at `<user>.github.io/<project>` with base href properly set. However, when trying to access the project page, I get redirected to the portfolio page, including the change in URL.

Both repositories are using a GitHub action that builds to the root of `gh-pages` branch. Both apps have their `index.html` file copied to `404.html`.

This is the route for the portfolio site:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
];
```

Accessing the URL `<user>.github.io/<project>` in my browser redirects me to `<user>.github.io` and displays a blank page with the layout of my portfolio site.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to switch to NextJS and my issue is solved. Invalid routes no longer fallback to 404 and will visit the project page if one exists. Otherwise, it will find GitHub pages' 404 page.